# Not allowing ONLY spaces in a form Angular Validatiom

Tags: html, angular, validation

Hey I have a little issue in a project I'm currently working on. I got some custom validations I made, but I cant figure out how to combine the NOT ONLY SPACES validation to my form. 
I need to distinguish it from my other Validations, meaning that its got its own error message.

this is my code so far:

component:

```
this.movieForm = this.fb.group({
  title: ['', [Validators.required,MyValidators.addMovieTitleValidator(this.dataService),MyValidators.spaceTitleValidator(this.dataService)]]
```

custom validators:

```
 static addMovieTitleValidator(dataService: DataService): ValidatorFn {
        return (control: AbstractControl) => {
            if (control.value && dataService.getTitles().includes(control.value.trim())) {
                return {
                    isError: true
                };
            }
            return null;
        }
}

static spaceTitleValidator(dataService: DataService): ValidatorFn {
        return (control: AbstractControl) => {
            if (control.value.trim().length<3) {
                return {
                    isError: true
                };
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

html:

```
 <mat-error *ngIf="!movieForm.get('title').hasError('required') && movieForm.get('title').touched && !movieForm.controls['title'].valid">
          A movie with this title already exists / Must provide at least 3 letters
        </mat-error>
```

right now if you enter only spaces or use title which exists you get this error:
[image: validation message]

How can I make it work so every messagr will be seen if needed and not together?
I mean if only spaces then "spaces error" if it exists then "exists" and so on.
I need to add another code in the html but I don't really know how to reference each validator separately since in the html the line that catch the error is:

> !movieForm.controls['title'].valid"

how can I divide this line into 2 validation options? one for spaces on for my custom?

Thanks by heart!

Comment: Hi, did the provided answer help? If it did please make sure you mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change validators to something like this:

```
static addMovieTitleValidator(dataService: DataService): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
        if (control.value && dataService.getTitles().includes(control.value.trim())) {
            return { 'addMovieTitleValidator': true };
        }
        return null;
    }
}

static spaceTitleValidator(dataService: DataService): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
        if (control.value.trim().length<3) {
            return {'spaceTitleValidator': true};
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and use in *html* like this:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="movieForm.get('title').hasError('required') && movieForm.get('title').touched && !movieForm.controls['title'].valid">
  Title is required
</mat-error>
<mat-error *ngIf="movieForm.get('title').hasError('addMovieTitleValidator') && movieForm.get('title').touched && !movieForm.controls['title'].valid">
  A movie with this title already exists
</mat-error>
<mat-error *ngIf="movieForm.get('title').hasError('spaceTitleValidator') && movieForm.get('title').touched && !movieForm.controls['title'].valid">
  Must provide at least 3 letters
</mat-error>
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-pbttcz) is simple example demonstrating how this works...